# How can I use INSERT data WHERE correctly in python (MySQLdb import)?

Tags: mysql-python

I am trying this code and keeps giving me errors.
I wanted the 3rd for cicle to add the role in the same line as the name in the table, so I was thinking using the WHERE to find the name, but something in the sql code is wrong I cant find what.

```html
for member in soup.findAll("div", {"class": "member-info"}):
    for membername in member.findAll("div", {"class": "member-name"}):
        print(membername.text)
        mn=membername.text
        cur.execute("""INSERT INTO team (name)
        VALUES (%s)""",
        [
        (membername.text)
        ])
    for memberrole in member.findAll("div", {"class": ""}):
        print(memberrole.text)
        cur.execute("""INSERT INTO team (role)
        VALUES (%s)
        WHERE name=%s""",
        [
        (memberrole.text),
        (mn)
        ])
db.commit()
db.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL INSERT always creates a new row. If you want to change something in an existing row (or several or all rows) **use UPDATE**, here `UPDATE team SET role=%s WHERE name=%s`.

Note if `name` is not defined as the table's (single-column) PRIMARY KEY or with a UNIQUE constraint, this code can create an additional row with the same `name` as an existing row, and if you repeat the process an unlimited number of such rows, and this UPDATE will affect all of them.